# Python: `key not in my_dict` but `key in my_dict.keys()`

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I have a weird situation. I have a dict, `self.containing_dict`. Using the debug probe, I see that dict's contents and I can see that `self` is a key of it. But look at this:

```
>>> self in self.containing_dict
False
>>> self in self.containing_dict.keys()
True
>>> self.containing_dict.has_key(self)
False
```

What's going on?

(I will note that this is in a piece of code which gets executed on a weakref callback.)

**Update:** I was asked to show the `__hash__` implementation of `self`. Here it is:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(
        (
            tuple(sorted(tuple(self.args))),
            self.star_args,
            tuple(sorted(tuple(self.star_kwargs)))
        )
    )

args = property(lambda self: dict(self.args_refs))

star_args = property(
    lambda self:
        tuple((star_arg_ref() for star_arg_ref in self.star_args_refs))
)

star_kwargs = property(lambda self: dict(self.star_kwargs_refs))
```

Comment: does self happen to implement its own '__hash__' ?

Comment: Are you sure this is really a dict, and not something with just the same interface? What is `self`? Does it have an `__eq__` redefined?

Comment: Is `self.containing_dict` just a Python `dict` or something like a `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`?  If the former, are keys or values of the dict themselves weakrefs?

Comment: Not an answer but `has_key` is deprecated - http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key - so maybe you should just not worry about it. :-)

Comment: @llasram and @Radomir: It's a normal Python `dict`.

Comment: @Ivo: Yes, `self` does have its own `__hash__` implementation!

Comment: You should post the `__hash__` implementation because that is definitely relevant for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you describe can only be caused by `self` having implemented `__eq__` (or `__cmp__`) without implementing an accompanying `__hash__`. If you didn't implement a `__hash__` method, you should do so -- normally you can't use objects that define `__eq__` but not `__hash__` as dict keys, but if you inherit a `__hash__` that may slip by.

If you do implement `__hash__`, you have to make sure it acts the right way: the result must not change over the lifetime of the object (or at least as long as the object is in use as a dict key or set item), and it must be consistent with `__eq__`. An object's hash value *must* be the same as objects it's equal to (according to its `__eq__` or `__cmp__`.) An object's hash value *may* be different from objects it's not equal to, but it doesn't have to be. The requirements also mean you can not have the result of `__eq__` change over the lifetime of the object, which is why mutable objects usually can't be used as dict keys.

If your `__hash__` and `__eq__` are not matched up, Python won't be able to find the object in dicts and sets, but it will still show up in `dict.keys()` and `list(set)`, which is what you're describing here. The usual way to implement `__hash__` methods is by returning the `hash()` of whatever attributes you use in your `__eq__` or `__cmp__` method.

Comment: I call wart!  The built in `object` defines a `__hash__`, so if you do the right thing and create a custom new style class (`X`), then override `__eq__`, Python will happily let you use your object as a dict key, while shortcutting to the base `object.__hash__` for the OPs case: 
`X() in {X(): None}`  Ugh.

Comment: It's not so much a wart as a *bug*, in Python 2.x. A bug introduced when new-style classes were introduced and that went unnoticed for a long time. It's fixed in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your `__hash__` method, the class stores references to its arguments, and uses that as a hash.  The problem is, those arguments are shared with the code that constructed the object.  If they change the argument, the hash will change and you won't be able to find the object in any dictionaries it had been in.

The arguments need not be anything complicated, just a simple list will do.

```
In [13]: class Spam(object) :
   ....:     def __init__(self, arg) :
   ....:         self.arg = arg
   ....:     def __hash__(self) :
   ....:         return hash(tuple(self.arg,))

In [18]: l = range(5)

In [19]: spam = Spam(l)

In [20]: hash(spam)
Out[20]: -3958796579502723947
```

If I change the list that I passed as an argument, the hash will change.

```
In [21]: l += [10]

In [22]: hash(spam)
Out[22]: -6439366262097674983
```

Since dictionary keys are organized by hash, when I do `x in d`, the first thing Python does is compute the hash of x, and look in the dictionary for something with that hash value.  The problem is, when the hash of an object changes after being put in the dictionary, Python will look at the new hash value, and not see the desired key there.  Using the list of keys, forces Python to check each key by equality, bypassing the hash check.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have custom hash and comparison defined for whatever class `self` is an instance and you mutated `self` after you added it to the dictionary.

If you use a mutable object as a dictionary key then after you mutate it you may not be able to access it in the dictionary but it will still appear in the `keys()` result.